Fill null values in a column based on records with same values on other columns
I have a dataset with N number of columns, let's say 3 to generate an example (n_1, n_2, n_3).
There are duplicate values based on some columns, as in:
import polars as pl

data = {
    'n_1': ['a', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'd', 'b', None, 'c', 'e'],
    'n_2': [1, 2, None, 3, 1, 2, 1, 3, 5],
    'n_3': [123, 345, 123, 567, 123, 987, 123, None, 923]
}
df = pl.DataFrame(data)

┌──────┬──────┬──────┐
│ n_1  ┆ n_2  ┆ n_3  │
│ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---  │
│ str  ┆ i64  ┆ i64  │
╞══════╪══════╪══════╡
│ a    ┆ 1    ┆ 123  │
│ b    ┆ 2    ┆ 345  │
│ a    ┆ null ┆ 123  │
│ c    ┆ 3    ┆ 567  │
│ d    ┆ 1    ┆ 123  │
│ b    ┆ 2    ┆ 987  │
│ null ┆ 1    ┆ 123  │
│ c    ┆ 3    ┆ null │
│ e    ┆ 5    ┆ 923  │

I want to fill the null values in each column with the value that is present in similar records, so that e.g. row 3 and 7 become ['a', 1, 123], row 8 becomes ['c', 3, 567].
EDIT: I forgot to add that that row 7 could become two rows and fill the values with both 'a' and 'b' so you have both [d, 1, 123] and [a, 1, 123].
EDIT 2: expected output:
┌──────┬──────┬──────┐
│ n_1  ┆ n_2  ┆ n_3  │
│ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---  │
│ str  ┆ i64  ┆ i64  │
╞══════╪══════╪══════╡
│ a    ┆ 1    ┆ 123  │
│ b    ┆ 2    ┆ 345  │
│ a    ┆ 1    ┆ 123  │
│ c    ┆ 3    ┆ 567  │
│ d    ┆ 1    ┆ 123  │
│ b    ┆ 2    ┆ 987  │
│ a    ┆ 1    ┆ 123  │
│ d    ┆ 1    ┆ 123  │
│ c    ┆ 3    ┆ 567  │
│ e    ┆ 5    ┆ 923  │

Do you know the optimal strategy to achieve this in plain SQL or Polars or Spark?
Thanks

It looks like row 7 could also become ['d', 1, 123]? What is the rule for choosing 'a' in this case?

@jqurious good point, I forgot to add that that row could become two rows and fill the values with both so you have both [d, 1, 123] and [a, 1, 123]. Adding to the main post

Can you add the actual full expected output dataframe? The wording sounds like you are saying row 7 should turn into 2 new rows? Meaning the result would have 10 rows (instead of 9). But I'm not entirely sure if I am understanding correctly?

also, if you want to turn one row into 2 rows then does order of rows in the final result matter?

@jqurious yes, row 7 should turn into 2 rows. Added expected output.

Making some assumptions here:

Only use rows where all the values are filled as 'replacement source'.
Matching 'replacement source' rows on 2 columns only.
If multiple possible choices found then all should be in the result.
Order of rows in the result does not matter.

cols = list(df.schema.keys())

df_new = [df.filter(pl.all_horizontal(pl.all().is_not_null()))]

for col_keys in combinations(cols, 2):
    col_value = set(cols).difference(col_keys)
    df1 = df.filter(pl.all_horizontal(pl.col(col_keys).is_not_null()))
    df_new.append(
        df1.filter(pl.col(col_value).is_not_null())
        .join(df1.filter(pl.col(col_value).is_null()), on=col_keys)
        .select(cols)
    )

pl.concat(df_new)

┌─────┬─────┬─────┐
│ n_1 ┆ n_2 ┆ n_3 │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ str ┆ i64 ┆ i64 │
╞═════╪═════╪═════╡
│ a   ┆ 1   ┆ 123 │
│ b   ┆ 2   ┆ 345 │
│ c   ┆ 3   ┆ 567 │
│ d   ┆ 1   ┆ 123 │
│ b   ┆ 2   ┆ 987 │
│ e   ┆ 5   ┆ 923 │
│ c   ┆ 3   ┆ 567 │
│ a   ┆ 1   ┆ 123 │
│ a   ┆ 1   ┆ 123 │
│ d   ┆ 1   ┆ 123 │
└─────┴─────┴─────┘


Clever! Thanks a lot!
